# Attach event to dynamic object

Tags: c#, .net, events, c#-4.0, dynamic

I create a c# dynamic object of a COM-Object on the fallowing way:

```
dynamic pdfCreator = Activator.CreateInstance(
                       Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator"));
```

The class clsPDFCreator is defining an event calling eReady. But when I try to register an Eventhandler like

```
pdfCreator.eReady += _PDFCreator_eReady;
```

I get the error message "Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'dynamic' and 'method group'".

**How can i register an EventHandler to an Event which is declared of a dynamic object?**

Comment: @Cicada - Sorry, I haven't made a mistake while simplifying the code. I have changed my post now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
public delegate void eReadyHandler();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator");
    dynamic pdfCreator = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);
    //dynamic pdfCreator = new PDFCreator.clsPDFCreator();

    //pdfCreator.eReady = null;
    pdfCreator.eReady += new eReadyHandler(_PDFCreator_eReady);
}

public static void _PDFCreator_eReady()
{

}
```

Comment: Will the "pdfCreator.eReady = null;" clear the previously attached event?

Comment: @TcKs - Most likely, but if you're going to set it again anyway then why would it matter?

Comment: So this solution is good idea only during initialization not in further user, understand it I right?.

Comment: @TcKs - Not necessarily. As I pointed out in my last comment, if you're overwriting the event anyway then why would it matter that you are clearing out the previously attached event before setting it?

Comment: @M.Babcock - sorry, I have forgotten the dynamic-Keyword in my post while simplifying the code - I have changed it now.

Comment: @M.Babcock - when I try your solution, I get the Exception: System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'eError'. But when I reference the COM-Object and cast pdfCreator to the right Interface, I can work with the event. But I want not reference the COM-Object.

Comment: @t.kehl - Has this helped you solve your problem or are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 8):

Since the delegate type is not known at compile time, you have to specify it. The `Action` delegate matches methods with no parameters or return value:

```
pdfCreator.eReady += new Action(_PDFCreator_eReady);
```

Comment: suppose the event handler has arguments like this public void _PDFCreator_eReady(object sender , MyCustomArgument e){ } In this case what will be the event registration code?

Comment: @Aneesh: `pdfCreator.eReady += new Action<object, MyCustomArgument>(_PDFCreator_eReady);`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using following as other options did not work. You might have to use generic of < T > if your EventHandler is a generic

```
pdfCreator.eReady += new System.EventHandler(_PDFCreator_eReady);
```