# Setting event handler for COM object using reflection?

Tags: c#, com

I'm creating a COM-object and can call all of its methods, get and set properties using comType.InvokeMember with different BindingFlags. The COM-object has a very huge interface, so it will be a lot of work for me to define it, and the object implements IDispatch.

Is there a way to add event handler for one of the object's events using reflection? I tried using comType.GetEvent to get EventInfo, but it could find it. Also there are no events found by comType.GetEvents either.

Comment: You don't *have to* "define" interfaces etc. you can use the `dynamic` c# keyword. Here is how it can work with dynamic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694235/attach-event-to-dynamic-object (basically, you'll still have to define a delegate)

Comment: @SimonMourier sadly I can't use it as I'm on .NET 3.5.

Comment: Well, there are add_EventName method, but I can't figure out how to call it with InvokeMember.